# Install AWS Redshift drivers Tableau Server not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I installed `AWS Redshift` drivers in `Tableau Server` using:

Download:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/odbc/1.4.27.1000/AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.27.1000-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Install:

```
sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.27.1000-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Install output is:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Examining AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.27.1000-1.x86_64.rpm: AmazonRedshiftODBC-64bit-1.4.27-1.x86_64
Marking AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.27.1000-1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package AmazonRedshiftODBC-64bit.x86_64 0:1.4.27-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                 Version                                Repository                                                                     Size
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 AmazonRedshiftODBC-64bit                               x86_64                               1.4.27-1                               /AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.27.1000-1.x86_64                                60 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 60 M
Installed size: 60 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : AmazonRedshiftODBC-64bit-1.4.27-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             1/1 
  Verifying  : AmazonRedshiftODBC-64bit-1.4.27-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             1/1 

Installed:
  AmazonRedshiftODBC-64bit.x86_64 0:1.4.27-1                                                                                                                                                                            

Complete!
```

When I test redshift connection I get this error:

```
Drivers needed not installed to connect to db.<br>2021-06-28 14:39:57.163, (YNnfPNRMIky5JaHdM7bkwwAAANQ,1:1
```

Comment: Have you installed actual ODBC support, in general, on your system?  if not, what you've done is like installing a printer driver, but not installing CUPS.

Comment: @MaxGanzII No, I haven't. I can't find any reference to that, i only find references to Database ODBC and not general ODBC support. Any idea how to do that? 

Doing this in AWS EC2 Linux 2 AMI. Does it have  the drivers by default?

Comment: Google for unixODBC.  I doubt it's installed by default on any Linux.  (BTW, note, you have already installed a driver; you are now installing the framework within which the driver operates.  Normally of course these two tasks are done the other way around, and for all I know you might have problems because they're being done in reverse order.)

Comment: @MaxGanzII Fixed, its related with the unixODBC, i installed and now failing due to server visibility

Answer (score 1):

downgrade the driver to 1.4.20.1001, any version after this is not compatible with tableau server.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/odbc/1.4.20.1001/AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.20.1001-1.x86_64.rpm